# Problema al estilizar Botón en HTML con CSS

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy tratando de poner un botón en HTML y lo estoy personalizando con CSS, pero a la hora de personalizarlo, el botón no toma el formato que le estoy ordenando con el CSS. Lo que yo hago es primero codificar con HTML, por ejemplo:

```
<a class="Boton1" href="Clientes 3.html">A Clientes 3</a>
```

y marco una división con div, para luego en el CSS poner y más,

```
div.Boton1{
   padding:10px
}
```

Pero al verlo en la página web, no se ve el botón con formato. Espero una respuesta y muchas gracias!

Esto es en HTML

```css
div.Boton1{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 30px;
    font-weight: 1200;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    background-color: #5be91e;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <link href="Estilo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="tit1">
        <img src="Imagenes/Logo Discor sin letras.png" alt="Logo de DisCor" width="239" height="60">

        <div class="Eslogan">

            <p align=left>
                <strong> Cerrajería y Accesorios del automotor </strong>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="Menu" align=left>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <br>
                <li><a href="Clientes.html">Clientes</a> </li>
                <br>
                <li><a href="Clientes 2.html">Clientes 2</a></li>
                <br>
                <li><a href="Clientes 3.html">Clientes 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="parrafo_inicial">
        <h2 align="center" style="font-family: Monaco, sans-serif, Pt Sans, comic sans;">
            <img style="float:right;" src="Imagenes/(Susp 7).jpg"
                alt="Se muestra la tapa de Discor, en él se encuentran dos Lamborghinis y en el medio el logo de DisCor"
                width="830" height="460">
            <div class="Primera_Caja_con_texto">
                <strong> N1 en el mercado automotriz, especializándonos en Cerrajería y Accesorios del automotor.
                </strong>
            </div>
        </h2>
        <a class="Boton1" href="Clientes 3.html">A Clientes 3</a>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Sigue sin poder vincularse

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias. El error es que me faltaba el punto

Answer (score 1):

El selector que estás usando es

`div.Boton1` (un elemento `div` con la clase `Boton1`)

Lo que necesitas es

`div .Boton1` (un elemento anidado en un `div` y con la clase `Boton1`)

El espacio (la falta de él) cambia el significado del selector y es lo que hace que no te funcione:

```css
div .Boton1{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 30px;
    font-weight: 1200;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    background-color: #5be91e;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="Boton1" href="Clientes 3.html">A Clientes 3</a> 
</div>
```

Si quieres hacerlo más restrictivo puedes usar

```
div > .Boton1
```

Que significa "elemento hijo (anidación de nivel 1 exclusivamente) de un `div` y que tiene la clase `Boton1`